# Error al sincronizar Gradle 4.6 en Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android-settings

Al actualizar AS 3.0 y el Gradle 4.6 me sale este error.

He intentado de todas las maneras. Instalación manual, SDk, limpiar cache, reconstruir, d3esde las dependencias, de forma manual en  Configuración > Gradle > Ruta del directorio > Aceptar. luego Reiniciar Android Studio,  etc, etc, etc y no logro sincronizarlo. He podido instalar la última versión disponible de gradle. (4.6) pero al tratar sincronizar el proyecto, no encuentra los archivos gradle.4.6.pom y gradle-4.6.jr en el directorio de proyectos. Lamentablemente no logro enconrtrarlos. Sinceramente, antes tenía el gradle 3.4 (un par de meses sin usar) y también me daba este mismo error. L a ñultima vez que funcionó todo ok, fue con la versión anterior de Android studio y el gradle 3.4. Alguna ayuda para ver luz en este problema?

Como dije. Según sistema la versión de Gradle 4.6 está instalada correctamente pero no sincroniza y no encuentra los archivos gradle-4.6.pom y gradle-4.6.jar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi Build Gradle completo es este:

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
       // maven {
       // url 'https://maven.google.com/'
       // name 'Google'
        // }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.6'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Y El error que sale al compilar En Build Gradle:

> Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources]
>   Information:BUILD FAILED in 1s Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an
>   exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'MeetMapp'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>   >     Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.6.
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          file/miDISCO C/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.6/gradle-4.6.pom
>   >          file/miDISCO C/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.6/gradle-4.6.jar
>   >          WEB jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.6/gradle-4.6.pom
>   >            tambien en WEBjcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.6/gradle-4.6.jar
>   >          wEBdl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.6/gradle-4.6.pom
>   >          wEBdl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.6/gradle-4.6.jar
>   >      Required by:
>   >          project :
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at GRADLE
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s
>
> Information:1 error Information:0 warnings Information:See complete
>   output in console

Y el error en Event Log:

> 12:35 Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources]
>
> 12:35 Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 1s 964ms
>
> 12:35 Gradle sync started
>
> 12:35 Gradle sync failed: Cause: startup failed:          build file
>   mIpcC:\Users\MARCOS\AndroidStudioProjects\MeetMapp\build.gradle': 17:
>   unexpected token: } @ line 17, column 1.          }           ^           1 error
>             Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1s 589ms)
>
> 12:35 Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug]
>
> 12:35 Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 723ms
>
> 13:00 Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources]
>
> 13:00 Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 1s 3ms
>
> 13:00 Gradle sync started
>
> 13:00 Gradle sync failed: Cause: startup failed:          build file
>   miPCC\Users\MARCOS\AndroidStudioProjects\MeetMapp\build.gradle': 20:
>   unexpected token: } @ line 20, column 1.          }           ^           1 error
>             Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1s 686ms)
>
> 13:00 Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug]
>
> 13:00 Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 789ms
>
> 13:01 Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources]
>
> 13:01 Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 2s 649ms
>
> 13:01 Gradle sync started
>
> 13:01 Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug]
>
> 13:01 Gradle sync failed: Could not find
>   com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.6.           Searched in the following
>   locations:            MiPC/Program Files/Android/Android
>   Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.6/gradle-4.6.pom
>             MiPC/Program Files/Android/Android
>   Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.6/gradle-4.6.jar
>             Webjcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.6/gradle-4.6.pom
>             Webjcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.6/gradle-4.6.jar
>             Webdl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.6/gradle-4.6.pom
>             Webdl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.6/gradle-4.6.jar
>             Required by:            project :           Consult IDE log for more details (Help
>   | Show Log) (2s 700ms)
>
> 13:01 Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 14s 416ms
>
> 13:04 Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources]
>
> 13:04 Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 2s 506ms
>
> 13:05 Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources]
>
> 13:05 Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 1s 936ms

Comment: He revertido tu última edición.No debes editar tu pregunta para ir adaptándola a lo que te vaya pasando. Puedes ampliar la pregunta si está relacionada, pero si es diferente, debes crear una pregunta nueva. Por otro lado, en lugar de pegar una captura de imagen, pega el texto de tu build.gradle y del error que te da

Comment: Perfecto... Gracias! iba a borrar la última edición. Entonces, tu consejo es que lo deje así, y abra una nueva pregunta con el error linea 17 columna 1?

Comment: Vale... he comentado el último } (se me ha olvidado) ... pero sale este error: Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'MeetMapp'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.6.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.6/gradle-4.6.pom y e-4.6.jar

Comment: Ok. Edita tu pregunta y añade toda esa información (sin borrar lo que hay). Añade el `build.gradle` y el error

Comment: Perfecto... pero al poner el error, hay varios links internos de mi PC. Y yo al ser novato, necesito 10 puntos mínimo para poner más de 8 links. No quisiera tocar el error...

Comment: De donde sacaste que la versión es 4.6 por cierto?  Yo creo que la ultima debe ser la 3.0.1 o por ahi. Intenta poner `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1` en lugar de `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.6`

Comment: Lo he sacado de aqui: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ . Lo único que si hago lo que tu dices, necesito descargar y poner el 3.01? Lo que si se es que esa actualización es de Android. Yo he pasado de 2.3 a 3.0.1 Pero el Gradle lo he bajado desde donde el enlace https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

Comment: No hace falta bajar nada,eso es el plugin de gradle para android studio. Simplemente cambia la linea que te digo y prueba

Comment: lo he hecho... y automáticamente me dice de que combiene actualizar y automáticamente me actualiza al 4.6. Me pone: To take advantage of all the latest features (such as Instant Run), improvements and security fixes, we strongly recommend that you update the Android Gradle plugin to version 4.6 and Gradle to version 4.1.  You can learn more about this version of the plugin from the release notes. Como has visto puedo instalar un gradle anterior pero me sigue tirando el error de que no encuentra el punto jar y el punto pom. Si lo tuviese, se lo pegaría para probar si es solo eso.

Comment: Ok,pues a ver si alguien mas puede ayudarte, por ejemplo @jorgesys :)

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu tiempo Pikoh. De verdad lo agradezco. Con respecto a @jorjesys no se si debo preguntarle directamente o quedare en stand by para cualquier otra ayuda. Gracias otra vez

Answer (score 1):

En la versión 3.0 de Android Studio se modificó el repositorio maven.

La solución a este error es eliminar la clave `maven` de `repositories`, y sustituirla por `google()`

Por otro lado, en tu `build.gradle` tienes `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.6`, cuando la ultima versión del plugin de gradle para Android Studio es la 3.0.1. Debes cambiar

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.6'
```

por

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```